# How to solve this error? websocket network error

Tags: reactjs, post, websocket, get

I tried to solve this error several ways. But I faild..

When I log in to my application for the first time, I get this error at first

Error msg: "websocket.js:143 WebSocket connection to 'wss://api.dino-run.site/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."

After a while, it changes to this error, but it seems that I can't communicate with the server at all.
Changed Error msg:
[image]

I deployed Client on netlify and Server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Client looks well and Backend also looks well. It works well on localhost but at https I don't know why this error exist and how can I search for solving this.

```
export const socket = io.connect(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`, {
  path: "/socket.io",
  transports: ["websocket"],
  withCredentials: true,
  cors: {
    origin: `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`,
  },
});
```

Backend socket code

```
module.exports = (server) => {
  const io = socketIO(server, {
    path: "/socket.io",
    cors: {
      origin: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`,
    },
  });

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {console.log("connection well")}
}
```

For solving this error, I tested ping between client and backend on localhost that working well but after deploying it doesn't work.
If you know it, please advice me.

Comment: after you deployed, did you set env variables on their platform

Comment: @Yilmaz yes I already set up env values on both platforms